# The macro: ISO_C_VISIBLE

Tags: c, macros

What is the purpose of this macro: `ISO_C_VISIBLE`? I found it in the `assert.h` file.

Is it used to know which C version we are using?

Comment: How do you expect us to give you an answer to such a thing if you don't specify OS, version and stuff like that.

Comment: why you need to know the OS? I asked generally, for any stuff you want!

Comment: Because *generally* `ISO_C_VISIBLE` does not exist.  It's not there on my system (Ubuntu 11.04), and since it's not in the implementation reserved namespace, an implementation that defines `ISO_C_VISIBLE` in `<assert.h>` is non-conforming.

Comment: Seems like it is a [configuration macro](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Open_Environment_Core/cdefs.hGlobals.html) used for Symbian. Don't know the purpose.

Comment: @user594778, generally if you tag your question more precisely with the OS for example, you might get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what an [OpenBSD `cdefs.h`](http://ftp.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/src/sys/sys/cdefs.h) has to say about `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` and some related macros:

```
/*
 * "The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from."
 * There are a number of "feature test macros" specified by (different)
 * standards that determine which interfaces and types the header files
 * should expose.
 *
 * Because of inconsistencies in these macros, we define our own
 * set in the private name space that end in _VISIBLE.  These are
 * always defined and so headers can test their values easily.
 * Things can get tricky when multiple feature macros are defined.
 * We try to take the union of all the features requested.
 *
 * The following macros are guaranteed to have a value after cdefs.h
 * has been included:
 *  __POSIX_VISIBLE
 *  __XPG_VISIBLE
 *  __ISO_C_VISIBLE
 *  __BSD_VISIBLE
 */
```

That particular `cdefs.h` sets `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` accrording to whatever POSIX specification level is configured.

So these are macros that BSD uses to attempt to 'condense' the other various feature macros used in the Unix world to configure a build environment into a more manageable set that other headers can rely on.

For example, setting the `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` macro appropriately (which the user will do indirectly by setting other documented feature macros) will allow older programs that might have names that conflict with C99 names continue to compile cleanly - if the build is properly configured, those conflicting C99 names will not be 'activated', the the use of those names in the user's program will not conflict.

If you look in the [`assert.h` file](http://ftp.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/src/include/assert.h) for that OpenBSD source drop, you'll see:

```
# if __ISO_C_VISIBLE >= 1999
#  define   assert(e)   ((e) ? (void)0 : __assert2(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, #e))
# else
#  define   assert(e)   ((e) ? (void)0 : __assert(__FILE__, __LINE__, #e))
# endif
```

So, if the build is configured to use C99 features the `assert` macro will take advantage of C99's `__func__` feature so an assertion will indicate which function the assertion was in. If the build is configured to indicate that C99 features should not be used, `assert()` won't do that.

Note that these macros are not a general standard - they seem to be mostly in the BSD world, but I'm sure you'll find other areas where they might be used (probably because files got borrowed from BSD).

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "ISO_C_VISIBLE" turns up this question and a handful of results for Nokia's Symbian operating system.  The [only description](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Open_Environment_Core/index.html) says:

> __ISO_C_VISIBLE 1999
>
> Description
>
> Macro value to enable for ISO_C_VISIBLE

My guess is that the value `1999` refers to the 1999 ISO C standard, but I see no further explanation of what it means or how it's used, or of the distinction between `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` and `ISO_C_VISIBLE`.  It seems odd because Symbian is primarily implemented and programmed in C++, not C.  And I certainly wouldn't expect it to be defined in `<assert.h>` (assuming that when you say `assert.h` you're referring to the header that's included by `#include <assert.h>`).

If you're not working with Symbian, then I have no idea what it might be.

The proper way to determine which C standard your implementation conforms to is to use the predefined **STDC** and **STDC_VERSION** macros.  For a conforming C90 or later implementation, `__STDC__` expands to `1`.  For a C99 implementation, `__STDC_VERSION__` expands to `199901L`.  For C11, it probably expands to `201112L`, but I haven't seen an actual copy of the new standard.

Answer (score 0):

These macros are used for configuring for the system compiling the code. Information gathered from the compiler is stored in them so the code is [shaped] according to the constructs supported by the hosting platform.

```
/* ... */
#ifdef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     200112
#define __ISO_C_VISIBLE     1999
#elif _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199506
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE     199506
/* ... */
```